# Python list of lambdas only taking last value

Tags: python, list, lambda

I'm trying to add lambdas to a list to be able to be called later. I have an example below but it is not working as expected. Only the last value in the loop is being used for the lambda calls in the list.

Code:

```
def print_value(x):
    print(x)

lambdas = []

for i in range(3):
    lambdas.append(lambda : print_value(i))

# Later on try to run the lambdas
for l in lambdas:
    l()
```

Output:

```
## Expected output
# 0
# 1
# 2

## Actual output
# 2
# 2
# 2
```

Why is my output not the expected output? I'm setting the value `i` in the initial loop and it's only taking the last value.

Comment: change to `lambdas.append(lambda i=i: print_value(i))`

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc that worked! What is happening under the hood?

edit: This is duplicated, I'll have a look at the other answers.

Comment: The idea of marking a duplicate is to save time for everything, you already saved time by finding an answer in a short time, now you save the time to explain to the community by reviewing the answers to the other questions, bye.

Comment: `i` binds to the global `i`, which at the end of the loop is 2. Need to bind it to local value for each iteration.